# How to get data from Database/Model with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP .NET, MVC and AngularJS so I'm trying to figure this all out still.

I have a Model called **Words.cs** which contains:

```
namespace liveSearch.Models
{
    public class Words
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Word{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

The database is already populated with data and I want to use JavaScript/JQuery to get every **Word** from the database so I can then manipulate that data in JavaScript etc.

I currently have Razor in my **index.cshtml** which does:

```
@{
     foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <li>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Word)
         </li>
     }
 }
```

This works in getting and displaying all Words in the model but I want to get rid of the Razor and use JavaScript/Jquery to get the data instead.

Ideally, I want to get all Words from the DB (I don't care about the IDs) and add it to an array in the scope in the .js file.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to access the DB with JavaScript or AJAX

I think I can use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` but I don't really know how to use it with a DB/model.

I also read a few other posts here on Stackoverflow that said this can be done, but I wasn't able to apply any of those examples to my case for some reason.

Comment: So you needto call the WbApi / Controller method from@ajax and use return data  andshow it in ui

Comment: Why would you want to do that. You can simply assign your model in the view to a javascript array using `var words = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` (then `words[0].Word` will return the value of the first `Word` property in your collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you will need to create an action method, which returns `Json`, in your controller. Something like this:

```
public JsonResult SomeAction()
{
   var list = context.Words.ToArray();
   return Json(list);
}
```

And then in your view you just use ajax to get the data:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "ControllerName")',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
  //the data parameter will be an array of objects. The objects will be of type Words
  //so data[0].Word(javascript) would be equal to list[0].Word in your SomeAction method(C#)
}
});
```

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` is pointless (its a GET and a GET has no body)

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it right away. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I get this error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on the `@Url.Action()`

Comment: I just hope that you didn't write "ControllerName" instead of the name of your controller. The `@Url.Action` is a helper method which(in this case) takes 2 parameters: the first is the name of the controller, and the second is the name of the action. So if the name of your controller(which the action "SomeAction" was defined in) is HomeController, then the `@Url.Action` would look like this: `@Url.Action("Home", "SomeAction")`

Comment: Instead of this, you could just write the link to your action: `url: '/Home/SomeAction'`, but this is a more convenient way (because of routing) in asp.net mvc.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around - it would need to be `@Url.Action("SomeAction", "Home")` (and always use `@Url.Action()` to generate the correct url - do not hard code it)

Comment: I didn't use ControllerName haha, I used my controllers name. It's ok I got it working. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, Stephen was right, I got it the other way around. It was my fault, I am terribly sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method on page load or button click where you want to get result .

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "yourControllerMethod",


    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    alert(data)
      // here you will get the json data.
      // now uisng jQuery you can run a loop and show the data where you want to do 
      }
 });
```

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` is pointless (its a GET and a GET has no body)